# Xpath Error: Expression must evaluate to a node-set

Tags: c#, xpath

I get title in html . And I get `Xpath` by firebug . But when run, it have error :

> Expression must evaluate to a node-set

```
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode linkNode in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/"))
{
    string imageLink = linkNode.InnerText.Trim();
    richTextBox1.AppendText(imageLink + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the trailing slash from the XPath expression.  It's not valid there.

The slash is basically a shorthand for the child axis.  So the expression as you have it is the same as

```
/html/body/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/child::
```

which of course expects another node test.  What you mean (I assume) is

```
/html/body/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td
```